# Sql Join between two tables using Entity framework - Trying to bind Gridview data from two tables

Tags: asp.net, linq, gridview, join

I have a gridview and originally I was binding data from one table (Table 1) and it was straightforward

```
gvUsers.dataSource = class.getUsers()
gvUsers.databind()

Function getUsers () As List (Of Users)
  Return (From X in Table1 Select x).ToList()
End Function
```

However, some of my data are pointing to another table and there is no relationship between tables ( no foreign key)

```
Table 1 
  UID   Name    Age     Blood Type   Test Type
  1     Sam       22          2           3        
  2     Jane      23          2           4
```

Table 2

```
ID  Domain    Code  Description
1   Blood Type  A   A
2   Blood Type  B   B
3   Test Type   1   1
4   Test Type   2   2
```

Currently In the gridView I see Blood Type as values 2 and Test type 3, 4 ( The second table ID) but I should get the Code column values in Table 2.
How can I join those two tables - I know if there is foreign key but the fact a column name is equivelant to row data name makes it hard for me to figure out!

Cheers

Comment: the other answer is not working, I tried

Comment: Sam, I am Updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Code

```
var result = (from p in Table1.AsEnumerable()
                   join Blood in Table2.AsEnumerable() on p.BloodType equals Blood .ID
                   join Test in  Table2.AsEnumerable() on p.TestTyoe equals Test .ID
                   select new With 
                   {
                       uid = p.UID,
                       Name = p.name,
                       Age = p.age,
                       BloodType = Blood.Code,
                       TestType = Test .Code
                   }).ToList();
```

Sql Query IS :

```
 select UID ,Name,Age,B.Code as BloodType ,T.Code as TestType From Table1
 inner join Table2 B on Table1.BloodType = B.ID
 inner join Table2 T on Table1.TestType= T.ID
```

The Used Vb then

```
Dim result = from p in Table1.AsEnumerable()
                   join Blood in Table2.AsEnumerable() on p.BloodType equals Blood .ID
                   join Test in  Table2.AsEnumerable() on p.TestTyoe equals Test .ID
                   select               
                        p.UID,
                        p.name,
                        p.age,
                        Blood.Code,
                        Test.Code                    

        gvUsers.DataSource = result
```

Comment: Thanks for your reposnse. However I am getting error in Select new ( type or with expected) .. var result - Is that allowed in VB ? the top part looks fine but if you could help with that error then will test it and let u know

Comment: Sam, I am Update Answer

Comment: sam Vb Format Updated

Comment: Unfortunately, different error now - uid = p.UID, Name = p.name. I understand its the column name = p.column name ( the left side is working but the right one which is column name is not recognized) the error is: uid Name is either not declared or not in the current scope!

Comment: Please Remove The Left Side Column name

Comment: [Help Link] http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/aj84/perform-queries-using-linq-in-VB-Net/

Comment: gvUsers.dataBind() - I am getting this error (System.String[]' cannot be initialized in a query result. Consider using 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' instead).. I changed the rest to the vb format didnt see your changes earlier. any idea how to fix that?

Comment: verify the gvUsers Grid Column Datatype Equal to Linq Query Result Data Type. The data type mismatch then pls convert the value

Comment: convert then using .AsEnumerable() in the  table1 and table2

Comment: Sorry,I don't understand your suggestion. I've looked at similar error and they had results as array. Could you break down the issue for me then will change my code accordingly, there are different data type for each column in the gridview (e.: datetime, string, integer)

Comment: Hi, I converted all the integer and date fields to string by doing convert.toString(p.age) and in the query for both tables I am ended it with .As Enumerable but its not working :( do u have any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select table1.*, table2.* from table1
inner join table2 on table1.Blood Type = table2.id
```

You can select you desired columns from both tables.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I am using LINQ and I tried from x in table1 join y in Table 2 on table1. ( its not picking up any columns) I am trying to convert your answer to linq